# All my Arrays pushed into an object changes when i change values in my input with the attribute ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this table in the frontend.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Numero de Asiento Contable </th>
                        <th> Fecha </th>
                        <th> Cuenta Contable </th>
                        <th> Descripcion </th>
                        <th> Debe </th>
                        <th> Haber </th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let asientoContable of asientosContables">
                        <td>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="id">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.fecha" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.ccontable.nombre" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.descripcion" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.debe" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.haber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button (click)="guardarHospital( hospital )" class="btn btn-primary">
                              <i class="fa fa-save">
                              </i>  
                            </button>
                            <button (click)="borrarHospital( hospital )" class="btn btn-danger">
                              <i class="fa fa-trash-o">
                              </i>  
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and in the module i have the next:

```
guardarPosicion( posicionAsiento: PosicionAsiento ) {


    this.asientoContable.posicionesAsiento.push( posicionAsiento );

    console.log(this.asientoContable);

  }
```

When I insert my first Array with the name "posicionAsiento" into the Object "asientoContable", the object will have this values:

fecha: ""
id: ""
posicionesAsiento: Array(1)
0: PosicionAsiento
ccontable: "2"
debe: "2"
descripcion: "2"
haber: "2"
id: 0
**proto**: Object
length: 1
**proto**: Array(0)
usuario: ""
_id: ""

But when I insert my second value, the old value override with the new value not only that when i change something on the Input it override all my Arrays on the Object "asientoContable" I don't understand why. Because I did the push already on the Object. Why the NgModel its linked with the Arrays inserted on the Object?

Thx for your help

Comment: Can you create a _minimal_ reproduction, preferably in Stack Blitz? I doubt that we need all these (non-English) names in order to understand the issue. It's confusing and hard to follow.

Comment: sorry that non-english names are propertys of the Array/Object. Next time i will translate it. I don't know how works Stack Blitz but i will try right now.

Comment: An object, such as `posicionAsiento`, is a reference type. Unless you use the `new` keyword, adding the same object to the array adds the *same* object to the array. So when you change any of its properties, you change the property in *all* of the array elements.

Where and how are you calling `guardarPosicion`? Is it passing in *new* instances of `posicionAsiento`?

Comment: I paste here my issue in the Stack Blitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkwzte  thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code. I believe it should work. 
change code like below

```
 <tr *ngFor="let asientoContable of asientosContables; let i = index; trackBy:i;">
```

add name property like

```
name="ID-{{i}}"
```

I have modified your code and use it

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Numero de Asiento Contable </th>
        <th> Fecha </th>
        <th> Cuenta Contable </th>
        <th> Descripcion </th>
        <th> Debe </th>
        <th> Haber </th>
        <th> </th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let asientoContable of asientosContables; let i = index; trackBy:i;">
        <td>
            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.id" name="id-{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="id">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.fecha" name="fecha-{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.ccontable.nombre" name="nombre-{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.descripcion" name="descripcion-{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.debe" name="debe-{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input [(ngModel)]="asientoContable.haber" name="haber-{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del asiento contable">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button (click)="guardarHospital( hospasientoContableital )" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-save">
              </i>  
            </button>
            <button (click)="borrarHospital( hospital )" class="btn btn-danger">
              <i class="fa fa-trash-o">
              </i>  
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Your Component Code should look like

```
guardarPosicion( posicionAsiento) {

this.asientosContables.push( new PosicionAsiento(posicionAsiento));

console.log(this.asientosContables);
```

}

Comment: I have also modified your code. I believe it will works

Comment: I have also modified on the component as well as a bit in HTML. Check this out.

Comment: didn't work this solution, i'm pasting the stackBlitz, i think i made a mistake pasting the frontEnd and that non-english words, thx for your help https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkwzte